How to insert to a database without looping with vb.net and Have an error Value cannot be null in CellEndEdit
I'm Trying to insert to a database without looping with vb.net and Have an error Value cannot be null in CellEndEdit
This post I refer to @dr.null
Actually, this is related to the previous post  link

In this code I create an insert to the database by looping from the DatagridView in Event Button (btninsert) Maybe the way I did it was wrong so I want no looping

below code reference to save without looping
To get the underlying data source with the original ProductName values:

Dim displayList = DirectCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, BindingList(Of Product))
Dim outputList = displayList.
    Select(Function(p) New Product With {
    .ProductName = dictProducts(p.ProductName).ProductName,
    .Unit = p.Unit
})
' ... etc.




so I have a problem also after I change 'DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows=False' then I bind to the binding source on do add new row via binding source then at that time do esc on the keyboard then there is an error Value cannot be null

in line below code in event CellEndEdit
 If String.IsNullOrEmpty(boundItem.Unit) AndAlso
                   dictProducts.TryGetValue(boundItem.ProductName, unit) Then



Is it possible that the code I implemented was wrong?
Please Guide me
Thanks
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports Dapper

Public Class customtextboxdgvautocomplete
    Private dictProducts As Dictionary(Of String, String)
    'Private BindingSource1 As BindingSource = Nothing
    Private bindinglist1 As New BindingList(Of ProductFinal)
    Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnLoad(e)
        dictProducts = ProductFinalService.GetDistinctProducts().
            ToDictionary(Function(p) p.ProductName, Function(p) p.Unit)
        'BindingSource1 = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = New BindingList(Of ProductFinal)}
        DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
        DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
        'DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bindinglist1        
        DataGridView1.Columns("Unit").ReadOnly = True
        'BindingSource1.AddNew()
        bindinglist1.AddNew() 

    End Sub
  Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(
        sender As Object,
        e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles _
        DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
        If TypeOf e.Control Is TextBox Then
            Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
            Dim tb = DirectCast(e.Control, TextBox)
            Dim cellRect As Rectangle = DataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex, DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex, True)
            If dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = dgv.Columns("ProductName").Index Then
                If tb.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Count = 0 Then
                    tb.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
                    tb.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(dictProducts.Keys.ToArray())
                End If
                tb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
            Else
                tb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None
            End If
  End If
    End Sub
   Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValidating(
        sender As Object,
        e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) _
        Handles DataGridView1.CellValidating
        Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)

        If e.ColumnIndex = dgv.Columns("ProductName").Index AndAlso
           e.RowIndex <> dgv.NewRowIndex Then
            Dim key = e.FormattedValue?.ToString()

            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(key) OrElse
               Not dictProducts.ContainsKey(key) Then
                Dim boundItem = DirectCast(dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem, ProductFinal)

                boundItem.Unit = Nothing
                dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = "Invalid Product!"
                dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("Unit").Index, e.RowIndex)
                e.Cancel = True
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValidated(
        sender As Object,
        e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValidated
        Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)

        If e.ColumnIndex = dgv.Columns("ProductName").Index Then
            Dim boundItem = TryCast(dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem, ProductFinal)
            If boundItem IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim value = dictProducts(boundItem.ProductName)
                If value <> boundItem.Unit Then
                    boundItem.Unit = value
                    dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("Unit").Index, e.RowIndex)
                End If
                dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = Nothing
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(
        sender As Object,
        e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
        Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
        Dim src = DirectCast(dgv.DataSource, bindinglist1))
        'Dim src = DirectCast(dgv.DataSource, BindingSource)
        If src.Count = e.RowIndex Then Return
        If e.ColumnIndex = dgv.Columns("ProductName").Index Then
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText) Then
                Dim boundItem = DirectCast(dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem, ProductFinal)
                Dim unit As String = Nothing

                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(boundItem.Unit) AndAlso
                   dictProducts.TryGetValue(boundItem.ProductName, unit) Then
                    boundItem.Unit = unit
                    dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("Unit").Index, e.RowIndex)
                    dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = Nothing
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form5_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


    End Sub
Private Sub Btninsert_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btninsert.Click

'With looping 
 'Try
            'Dim ProductFinalService As New ProductFinalService()
            'For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                'Dim outputList = New ProductFinal With {
            '.ProductName = CStr(row.Cells(0).Value),
            '.Unit = CStr(row.Cells(1).Value)
            '}
                'ProductFinalService.InsertProductsoption3(CType(outputList, 'ProductFinal))
            'Next
            'MessageBox.Show(Me, "Successfull")
        'Catch err As Exception
            'MessageBox.Show(Me, err.Message)
        'End Try

`without looping Error  BC30456 Select is not a member of BindingSource
 'Try
            'Dim ProductFinalService As New ProductFinalService()
            'Dim displayList = 'DirectCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, BindingSource)
            'Dim outputList = displayList.
            'Select(Function(p) New ProductFinal With {
            '.ProductName = dictProducts(p.ProductName),
            '.Unit = p.Unit
        '})
            'ProductFinalService.InsertProducts(outputList)
            'MessageBox.Show(Me, "Successfull")
        'Catch err As Exception
            'MessageBox.Show(Me, err.Message)
        'End Try
    `without looping via bindinglist1 No errors and successful
Try
            Dim ProductFinalService As New ProductFinalService()
            Dim displayList = DirectCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, bindinglist1)
            Dim outputList = displayList.
            Select(Function(p) New ProductFinal With {
            .ProductName = dictProducts(p.ProductName),
            .Unit = p.Unit
        })
            ProductFinalService.InsertProducts(outputList)
            MessageBox.Show(Me, "Successfull")
        Catch err As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(Me, err.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
  Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean
        If keyData = Keys.Tab AndAlso CBool(Keys.Enter) Then
            If Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                If DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index = (DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1) Then
                    bindingSource1.AddNew()
                End If
            Else
            End If
            Return True
        End If
        Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
    End Function


End Class
Public Class ProductFinalService
    Private Shared Function GetOledbConnectionString() As String
        Return "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
                    Data Source=|DataDirectory|\test03092024option1.accdb;
                    Persist Security Info=False;"
    End Function

    ' ...

    Friend Shared Function GetDistinctProducts() As IEnumerable(Of ProductFinal)
        Dim sql = "SELECT DISTINCT ProductName, Unit 
                       FROM Products 
                       ORDER BY ProductName"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            Return _conn.Query(Of ProductFinal)(sql)
        End Using
    End Function

    Public Sub InsertProductsoption3(ByVal Obj As ProductFinal)
        Dim sql = "INSERT INTO saveproducts (ProductName,Unit) VALUES (@ProductName,@Unit);"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            _conn.Execute(sql, New With {
    Key Obj.ProductName,
    Key Obj.Unit
})
        End Using
    End Sub
        Public Sub InsertProducts(Obj As IEnumerable(Of ProductFinal))
        Dim sql = "INSERT INTO saveproducts (ProductName,Unit) VALUES (@ProductName,@Unit);"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
_conn.Execute(sql, obj)
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class ProductFinal
    '<Browsable(False)>
    'Public Property Font As String = "☑️"

    Public Property ProductName As String
    Public Property Unit As String

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"{ProductName} {Unit}"
    End Function

End Class



Could it be that one of boundItem or boundItem.ProductName is Nothing when you try to access the dictionary? I would help if you inserted the full error meassage. Also, maybe you can find the bug by debugging.

@OlivierJacot-Descombes , thanks for response , I've updated in the post and the error is like this unable to cast object of type system.windows.form.bindingsource to type system.componentmodel.bindinglist  in button event (btninsert) and for this Could it be that one of boundItem or boundItem.ProductName is Nothing  You're right how can I handle the problem? .

@OlivierJacot-Descombes , for error Value cannot be null error doesn't appear if I comment out the code DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False and BindingSource1.AddNew() But I want the user to add row with keyboard shortcuts

dictProducts.TryGetValue(If(boundItem?.ProductName, ""), unit). The ?. is the null-conditional operator and the If(,) is the If-Operator. You are trying to convert a BindingSource instead of bindingsource.DataSource to a BindingList.

The answer you pointed to does not use any BindingSource. Use the original code and where you want to add new record by code, cast the DataGridView.DataSource to BindingList<ProductFinal> and add a new ProductFinal object to the list. That's it.

@OlivierJacot-Descombes , Thank you for your response. dictProducts.TryGetValue(If(boundItem?.ProductName, ""), unit) Your code solves the error Value cannot be null

@dr.null , Thank you for your response. in button event (btninsert) Dim displayList = DirectCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, BindingList(Of ProductFinal)) means if I use a DataGridView datasource to a bindingsource then I can't insert to database without looping. Please Guide me

Says who? Now, do you have an insert method that takes IEnumerable(Of YourMode> or not? I don't see one in ProductFinalService class. You need to pass the BindingList(Of YourModel) to some: Shared Sub InsertProducts(products as IEnumerable(Of YourMode)) and pass the products param to the .Execute method. The loop works because you are calling the method that you have which takes and inserts a single YourModel param. Makes any sense to you? Learn from your own code, from another context in your project, what code is there that inserts a collection of objects into the database.

@dr.null , do you have an insert method that takes IEnumerable(Of YourMode> or not?  Yes I don't have,  You need to pass the BindingList(Of YourModel) to some: Shared Sub InsertProducts(products as IEnumerable(Of YourMode)) and pass the products param to the .Execute method.  I'll try

@dr.null , I've updated in the post Public Sub InsertProducts(Obj As IEnumerable(Of ProductFinal))  but the error ProductName is not a member of IEnumerable(Of ProductFinal) & Unit is not a member of IEnumerable(Of ProductFinal) please guide me

_conn.Execute(sql, obj)

@dr.null  , _conn.Execute(sql, obj) thanks Your code solves the error.  I've updated the code posted in the button event without looping status insert to database successfully but The problem is that after I do the insert record in the database the productname becomes a unit and for the unit it is appropriate. Dim displayList = DirectCast(BindingSource1.DataSource, BindingList(Of ProductFinal)) Is this true ? . Please Guide me

Use the original code you pointed to, get rid of the BindingSource, include from here the new insert method and pass to it the outputList from the first code snippet. Btw, that answer contains two different examples so don't cocktail them. Use the second one as I understand your requirements.

@dr.null , I have error in button event ErrorBC30456 Select is not a member of BindingSource with code Dim displayList = DirectCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, BindingSource) please guide me

You don't listen. Read the previous comments carefully. Use the original code and remove the BindingSource from your code. Stick with the BindingList(Of T).

@dr.null , thanks for your response. I have updated in the post via bindinglist insert to the database without looping the result is successful but if via bindingsource is it possible it can be applied without looping the insert to the database

Note that if you are not sure about the type stored in a variable or property, then you can set a breakpoint on the code line, and when the execution stops there, you can hover over the variable or property and the type will be revealed. You can also open the Locals window or the Autos window or the QuickWatch window. They will all reveal the type and the value.

@OlivierJacot-Descombes , Sorry I'm Late reply. Thanks for your suggestion. I have another latest post maybe you can help or also give me suggestions or solutions This link
